# Changing a complex join into a Sequel association

Tags: mysql, ruby, join, model, sequel

Right now I have a relatively complex piece of code (it's not that complex) that I'd like to simplify through Sequel associations

```
MyApp::Model::Node.where { last_heartbeat > Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds }.join(:system_status, node_id: Sequel.expr(:node__id))
```

Pretty nasty, this statement.

So I'd like to accomplish one thing, pretty much: simplify the above statement by replacing the join with an association in my `SystemStatus` Model.

Let me explain the above join:

I have two tables `Node` and `SystemStatus`. The comparison `last_heartbeat > Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds` essentially gives me all the "live nodes" in my application (my application is clustered, meaning the user can spawn multiple instances of it at the same time).

So that mess of a statement gives me "all the statuses of my live nodes" which is joined by `system_status.node_id` to `node.id`.

So I started this out by establishing my one to one relation in `SystemStatus` - this sets the association to the `node` table

```
one_to_one :node
```

Next, I needed to join it by a specific key `node.id` because it's not a straightforward join

```
one_to_one :node, key: :id
```

But my question is:

1. How do I do the rest of this association
2. Should I perform the association in `Node` as opposed to `SystemStatus`? It seems I could simply do `one_to_one :system_status` and not have to specify a key.. The above complex join resides in the `node` Model anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the association in `SystemStatus`, you need to use `many_to_one`, as the foreign key is in the that model's table, not the associated model's table.  You can just transfer your where condition to the association using a block:

```
SystemStatus.many_to_one :live_node, class: :Node, key: :node_id do |ds|
  ds.where{last_heartbeat > Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds}
end
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when I try the above statement, it's saying `undefined method 'node_id' for #<MyApp::Model::Node:0x37ae1d57>`. Seems to be trying to interpret `node_id` as a method